# customtkinter как сделать, чтобы фрейм, который я скроллю, появлялся в самом верху canvas, и, чтобы я не мог проскроллить выше него?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

По нажатию кнопки в scrollable_frame будет добавляться другой фрейм с контентом, но когда я добавляю фрейм он не заполняет весь canvas и я могу прокрутить его выше. Как сделать так чтобы нельзя было прокручивать выше данного окна с фреймом?

```
from customtkinter import *

#main window
root=CTk()
root.title('DAC')
root.minsize(700,700)
root.maxsize(700,700)

#######################################################################
#define link send command
#######################################################################
def link_send():
    match_frame = CTkFrame(games_scrollable_frame, border_color='#296591', border_width=4, width=games_scrollable_frame.winfo_width())
    match_frame.pack()
    adv_frame = CTkFrame(match_frame, width=match_frame.winfo_width())
    adv_frame.pack(pady=(0, 2))
########################################################################
#make module to insert and submit link
########################################################################
link_entry=CTkEntry(root)
link_entry.pack(fill=X)

Link_send_button=CTkButton(root,text='+ Add Game',height=50,command=link_send)
Link_send_button.pack(fill=X)

##############################################
#making frame with scroll and inside frame to add matches
##############################################
games_container=CTkFrame(root)
canvas=CTkCanvas(games_container,bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
scrollbar=CTkScrollbar(games_container,orientation=VERTICAL,command=canvas.yview)
games_scrollable_frame=CTkFrame(canvas,width=canvas.winfo_width(),height=canvas.winfo_height(),border_color='green',border_width=1000)

games_scrollable_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)
canvas.create_window((0,0),window=games_scrollable_frame,anchor="nw")
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

#canvas.configure(bg='#2b2b2b')

games_container.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=BOTH,expand=1)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=1)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)

label=CTkLabel(games_scrollable_frame,text='####################################').pack(pady=30)
#######################################
#scrolwheel binding to scrollbar
#######################################

def _on_mousewheel( event):
    canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>",_on_mousewheel)

##############################################
##############################################
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Вы хотите чтоб фреймы добавлялись сверху а не снизу?

Comment: Контент scrollable_frame отображается в середине canvas, и scrollbar не работает корректно( контент можно промотать таким образом, что он останется в самом низу, а вверху будет пустота) , пока scrollable_frame не наполнится достаточным количеством контента, чтобы его заполнить. Если вам не сложно, то вы можете запустить мой код. В таком случае вам будет лучше понятно что я имею ввиду.  Scrollable frame отображается как бы по середине canvas и расширяется сразу и вверх и вниз, а мне надо, чтобы он отображался вверху canvas и расширялся только вниз.

Comment: То есть вы хотите выключить скроллинг, пока контента не станет достаточно?

Comment: Вообще я бы хотел, чтобы именно контент начинался сверху canvas. Но то что вы написали, по идее, тоже подходит. Попробую реализовать ваш вариант.

Comment: Было бы очень кстати, если бы вы подсказали как можно это реализовать.